# definition of Krull dimension of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. We know that the *Krull dimension of $R$* is by definition the length of the longest chain of prime ideals of $R$.

Now if $M$ is a  $R$-module, the [*Krull dimension of $M$*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) is by definition $\dim(M):=\dim(R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M))$. Since every ideal $I$ of $R$ is also a $R$-module, the Krull dimension of $I$ is $\dim(I)=\dim(R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(I))$.

However, in the literature, the Krull dimension of an ideal is $\dim(I):=\dim(R/I)$.

**Are the two definitions equivalent?**

Comment: I only remember this convention because if $R$ is a domain then using $R/\operatorname{Ann}_R(I)$ is really silly.

Comment: @Leon: Eisenbud comments on the non-equivalence of these definitions in his book: see page 226. Is your textbook silent on the matter?

Comment: @Zhen: Thanks for the reference! I use [Grillet](http://www.amazon.com/Abstract-Algebra-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/1441924507/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325957420&sr=1-1), [Greuel&Pfister](http://www.amazon.com/Singular-Introduction-Commutative-Algebra/dp/3540735410/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325957458&sr=1-1), [Kemper](http://www.amazon.com/Course-Commutative-Algebra-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/3642035442/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325957458&sr=1-4). There is very little said on the matter so far.

Answer (score 4):

They are not equivalent, but this never (?) leads to confusion.

Suppose for example that $R$ is a domain, so that $\mathrm{ann}_RI=0$. Then seeing $I$ as a module gives $\dim I=\dim R$, which the other definition gives $\dim I=\dim R/I$, which are usually different —for a boring example, take $R=k[x]$ and $I=(x)$.

Of course, since you had to ask it is clear that that *never* I used above needs some qualification. But as soon as you get used to the funny convention the confusion disappears. Perhaps one should say that *ït never leads* again *to confusion after one has unconfused oneself*... Commutative algebra is fun!

Comment: Aha, a counterexample would be: $R=K[x,y], M=I=\langle y\rangle$. Then $dim(R/I)=dim(K[x])=1\neq2=dim(K[x,y]/0)=dim(R/\mathrm{Ann}_{R}(I))$. Hmm, is there any reason to define the Krull dimension of a module that way? I mean, it doesn't agree with the dimension of the ideal, nor with the vector space dimension when $R$ is a field? Does it at least agree with "longest chain of submodules of M"? I'm guessing not, since the case $M=_RR$ would mean $dim(R)=$longest chain of ideals, which is wrong, since we must consider only prime ideals.

Comment: dim(M)= dim( Supp (M)) as an algebraic variety in Spec(R)